# Can't set node.js env

Tags: node.js, npm, env

I'm using windows 7. I try to use `SET NODE_ENV="development"` command from cmd but this won't help. Also in npm in scripts I use `NODE_ENV=development` node app.js. But env still undefined.

Comment: How are you checking to see if env is undefined?

Comment: process.env.NODE_ENV

Comment: If you open a blank command-prompt and you write `SET NODE_ENV= "development"` and then `echo %NODE_ENV%`, what is the result?

Comment: I would suggest assuming development unless the NODE_ENV is set to production, allowing you to not care if your dev environment has said variable.

Comment: "development" but in the project undefined

Comment: I try to use logger but he should know what the env

Comment: that shouldn't require the env var to be set outside the application, what logger are you using?

Comment: I'm using winston
ENV  = process.env.NODE_ENV; ... level: ENV == 'development' ? 'debug' : 'error',

Comment: `ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';`

Comment: Thank you very much, it works! But is there some solution  for getting env from  
process.env.NODE_ENV I use this log log.info('Express server listening on port ' + port + ' in ' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ' mode'); and every time before mode there is undefined

Comment: yes, properly set the environment variable. :) I'd suggest finding documentation on that subject based on what OS you're using.

Comment: @OlegBaranovsky can you try this

create a file env.js with this line
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);

Then from the command prompt

>set NODE_ENV=development
>node env.js

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc755104.aspx

Comment: @ bluesman yes I did it and result is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "set NODE_ENV=development&& node app.js" 
}
```